# Customizing WordPress pre-publishing sidebar

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

WordPress provides pre-publishing checks, and I need to add more checkings to this list.

[image: Pre-publish checklist]

I've tried unsuccessfully to find any documentation related to this feature. I even tried to read the Yoast source code that has steps on this sidebar, but I couldn't find anything helpful there.

I've also seen there are some plugins to create checklists, but I want to append new items to this existing list using only WordPress resources.

Comment: I've found a place explaining how we can do that.
https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/slotfills/plugin-pre-publish-panel/